# How to run test from different folder?

Tags: java, maven

I have project

```
my-tests
  src
    test
      java
        my
          demo
srv
  src
    main
      java
        my
          demo
```

I want to run mvn clean install on srv and then to run the tests from my-tests
I tried to add plugin to the pom.xml of srv

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.12</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>add-test-source</id>
     <goals>
       <goal>add-test-source</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <sources>
         <source>../my-tests</source>
       </sources>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I got an error of compile

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.592 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-27T16:35:14+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project sapinttest-srv: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/company/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[3,22] package io.restassured does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/company/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[4,47] package org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/demo/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[5,34] package org.jboss.arquillian.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/demo/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[6,37] package org.jboss.arquillian.test.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/demo/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[7,37] package org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users//Downloads/app/integration-tests/src/test/java/my/demo/HelloWorldServletTest.java:[8,17] package org.junit does not exist
```

when I tried to run test from the  my-tests folder the compile was ok but the tests didn't run
`mvn clean install -DskipTests=false`

Could you advise me please ?

Comment: Are you really sure you need this project layout? Using standards is usually easier...

Comment: what do you mean standards  ? that the test under srv folder ?

Comment: I mean that in a standard Maven project, you find the source code in `src/main/java` and the tests in `src/test/java` (as subdirectories of the project root).

Comment: so it is the my-tests folder is in src/test/java and I want that the srv will run them

Comment: I succeed to run the test but I got an compile error

Comment: Separate different types of test via naming conventions than via separate directories cause different directories is harder to configure...

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing compilation errors

The error message states that some third library packages could not be found.
Being `my-tests` a Maven module, you should add to its `pom.xml` the dependencies that contains these packages.

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.13.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- TODO: Add other dependencies here. -->
   </dependencies>
   ...
</project>
```

To find which dependency contains the package, you could search on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/) using the following criteria:

```
fc:package-name
```

e.g.:

```
fc:org.jboss.arquillian.junit
```

Direct link: https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.jboss.arquillian.junit

### Changing the test folder

Being your goal simply running tests on a folder different than `src/test/java`, you should change the [testSourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory) property.

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
   <build>
      <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/custom-test-folder/java</testSourceDirectory>
   </build>
   ...
</project>
```